# i was trying to run the cmd "apt-get update "but it is showing me this error constantly

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-19.04

whenever i am trying this cmd "apt-get update"
it is showing me failure and suggesting to do update but whenever i try that the following is shown
i tried the answer given for similar question, but that didn't work for me.

```
Err:1 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease        
  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease      
  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease          
Hit:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com disco InRelease          
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease            
Hit:11 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                 
Hit:10 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the source which is not working? I think you have to tidy up your apt configuration files. Take a a look at all the files under ```/etc/apt```

Comment: what source are you talking about, sir ? can you please explain in brief.@Dr.-Ing.GerhardStein

Comment: I mean the entries you find in the text files under ```/etc/apt```. The lines you see are called sources.